# java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/log4j/Appender.class

Tags: android, logging, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library, android-multidex

In my android application i got below error when I run the app.I am not sure what this error means.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/log4j/Appender.class
```

Does I need to exclude anything from the dependency configuration.I'm not sure about what there about duplicate entry.
I getting below warning also.

```
Warning:WARNING: Dependency commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
```

Below is my dependency config.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.esp.office"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0'
    compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:2.0.0.M3'
    compile('org.springframework.android:spring-android-auth:2.0.0.M3') {
        exclude module: 'spring-core'
    }
    compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-core:2.0.0.M3'
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.5.2.RELEASE')
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.3'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.0'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.0'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.0'

    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'net.sourceforge.jexcelapi:jxl:2.6.12'
    compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'
    compile 'com.github.ganfra:material-spinner:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.wseemann:FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever:1.0.14'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:1.3.2'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '26.1.0'
            }
        }
    }

}
```

build.gradle :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone" }

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Error does not show up during gradle sync. Just when I try to run the application and its not going.

What could be the problem?

Comment: use `compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.6'` instead of `compile 'commons-io:commons-io:1.3.2'`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya it didn't worked